# How can i strip off the br tags from my echoed text from the mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

Am using a textarea to add data to mysql database using php, and am using nl2br to format my text before inserting it into the database, the challenge comes when it comes to echoing out data it comes out in the format

```
Introduction<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

Open Source's Proponents Often Claim That It Offers Significant Benefits When Compared To Typical Commercial Products. Commercial Products Typically Favour Visible Features (giving Marketing Advantage) Over Harder-to Measure Qualities Such As Stability, Security And Similar Less Glamorous Attributes. As A Shorthand, We Shall Describe This Phenomenon As Quality Vs Features.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

how can i remove the `<br />`s i have used the `strip_replace`, `nl2br` but it has all failed. I need help sincerely,thanks

Comment: The tags cant display here but the whole text is full of breaks

Comment: Spend some time and read manual page about `nl2br`.

Comment: strip_replace??? or str_replace?

Comment: Use regular expressions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression or try `strip_tags` (before echoing the string) in your case.

`strip_tags` — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

> Syntax:
>   string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
>
> This function tries to return a string with all NULL bytes, HTML and
>   PHP tags stripped from a given str.
>
> This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you
>   allow using allowable_tags, including the style and onmouseover
>   attributes that a mischievous user may abuse when posting text that
>   will be shown to other users.